# Why is WebStorm not showing suggestions for anode.parentNode.classList? In fact it is underlining it as wrong

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, webstorm, syntax-highlighting

So I have noticed sometimes WebStorm does not show proper suggestions with JavaScript and even underlines valid code as wrong. In this case, the missed suggestion happens with this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =\> {

    //Get form and required fields
    const form = document.querySelector("#mainForm");
    const required = document.querySelectorAll(".required");
    form.addEventListener('submit', validateForm);      //Add Listener to submit form
    
    function validateForm(e) {
        //Check if title is blank
        if (required[0].value === "" || required[0].value == null) {
            required[0].parentNode.classList.add("highlight");      //Add to parent
            required[0].classList.add("highlight");                 //Add to child 
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        //Check if checkbox is checked
        if (!required[2].checked || required[2].value == null) {
            required[2].parentNode.classList.add("highlight");     //Highlight parent (box)
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

});
```

The problem is in `required[0].parentNode.classList.add("highlight")` WebStorm underlines `.classlist` as wrong. In fact when I type `required[0].parentNode.` it does not suggest `classList` as an option. I checked it with VS Code and VS Code does make that suggestion.

Does anybody know why and how to fix it, so that WebStorm gives me correct suggestions in this case?

I was expecting to show `.classList` as an option as VS Code does but it is not doing it. I like WebStorm a lot more, but this has happened before in the past, making me think I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs because the exact type of `required[0].parentNode` is not known (can't be retrieved statically) and the property `classList` does not exist on type `ParentNode`. You need letting the IDE know what the element actual type is (using JSdoc annotations, for example)